# Meter en una variable JAVASCRIPT, valor mostrado por BLADE

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent

Al tratar de introducir el valor mostrado por BLADE en una variable de JAVASCRIPT devuelve un error de sintaxis. ¿Cómo debería ser la sintaxis de concatenación?

```
function comprobar(){
var respuesta1 = "
  {{pregunta->respuesta1}}
";
...
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres concatenar? y que resultado esperarías?

Comment: Concatenar no sería la palabra, disculpa. Símplemente insertar el valor mostrado por BLADE en la variable JAVASCRIPT. No es una concatenación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript no te permite tener cadenas de texto en multilineas, a menos que en tu ejemplo uses el operador `\`, pero como no es mucho texto lo que necesites, solo haz lo siguiente:

```
function comprobar(){
var respuesta1 = "{{ $pregunta->respuesta1 }}";
...
}
```

Y si quisieras concatenar solo añade la otra cadena con el operador `+`:

```
var respuesta1 = "{{ $pregunta->respuesta1 }}" + "otro texto";
```

Creo que debes de diferenciar entre concatenar y asignar un valor, concatenar es unir dos o más cadenas de texto, asignar es establecer.

Answer (score 1):

No es posible insertar strings multilínea en JavaScript, **excepto** que uses ` (backtick):

```js
var respuesta1 = ` 
  {{pregunta->respuesta1}}
`;

console.log(respuesta1)
```

De otra manera, le tienes que sacar los saltos de línea:

```js
var respuesta1 = "{{pregunta->respuesta1}}";

console.log(respuesta1)
```

De paso, el backtick te permite insertar variables dentro:

```js
const a = "una variable";

const b = `mi 
string 
con 
${a}`;

console.log(b);
```